# Integrate $f(x,y) = \sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}$ inside circle with radius 2 and center $(2,0)$

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates

An exercise asks to integrate

$$f(x,y) = \sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}$$

inside circle with radius 2 and center $(2,0)$.

When I set up the double integral I get

$$\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_{0}^{4cos(\theta)} \sqrt{4-r^2} r dr d\theta$$

Is that the correct way to set up the integral?

Should I really evaluate that as

$$
- \frac{1}{2} \int_{\frac{-\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_{0}^{4-16cos^2(\theta)} u^{1/2} du d\theta = - \frac{1}{3} \int_{\frac{-\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} u^{3/2}\bigg|_{0}^{4-16cos^2(\theta)} d\theta = \cdots
$$

which seems like a dead-end?

Comment: I wonder about the intent of the exercise. The point $(3,0)$ is inside the circle of radius $2$ centered at $(2,0)$. What is $f(3,0)$?

Comment: @DavidK you mean that the point (3,0) is not defined?

Comment: Yes; actually the same question applies to any point with $x^2 + y^2 > 4$, which is more than half of the region of integration.

Comment: @DavidK couldn't agree more. Nevertheless, let's say that made sense (which it does not!). Is my integral correct? (the set-up)

Comment: Aside from the problem itself, I don't see any errors in the setup or calculations.

Comment: @DavidK ok thank you for your time. Best Regards!